# Bitcoin cash to Bitcoin wallet

Tags: cross-chain-recovery

Apparently I am not alone in feeling foolish regards this. 
I think things are safe, but would so much appreciate advice. 
When using Coinbase, I had some small change in my Bitcoin Cash wallet, don't know how it got there, as I always use standard Bitcoin. 
Anyways I deposited into my Bitcoin CASH wallet. 
I then sent the Bitcoin Cash to a standard Bitcoin address, of which I have access to. 
So it has been sent to a one off address which is mine. 
Can any of you kind folk tell me what will happen?

Comment: Coinbase says its lost, even though I have seen answers that it can be retrieved.

Comment: Can someone put me out of my misery please by confirming if this transaction is floating in the aether never to be seen again.

Answer (score 1):

If you sent Bitcoin Cash to a standard Bitcoin address you can still get to it (maybe).

There is too little to give you a fully correct answer. If the address is a wallet you control (not an exchange) then you should have a recovery password. It is possible to restore your BTC wallet into a BCH wallet, then transfer the funds from there.

I'm assuming you didn't accidentally send the coins to a Segwit address.

What would help the most, if you provided the transaction ID and the name of the wallet you use. (provide the path: Eg, Coinbase BCH > Exodus BCH > Coinbase BTC)

I can look into it a bit, make sure the tokens were transacted etc. Beyond that, i'm far more familiar about how to deal with this if you were running a bitcoin core node.

Comment: Im walking my dog, Coinbase have told me its a lost cause.

Comment: I'd need the the path of transactions first. I need to know who owned the wallet(s) at what point. If the final destination is indeed a Coinbase 1-off, then no. They won't bother with it.

Comment: Im going to give my dog the timehe deserves then maybe Ican go into this further with you if you dont mind, i really appreciate your time Cleanmarker

Comment: No worries. I'll check back on this. Let your dog do his/her thing. (I have 2 myself!)

Comment: Hi cleanmarker,

Comment: There is no rush on this, I can access the destination bitcoin cash address my money is sitting in looking into the transaction details in coinbase. Not going anywhere it seems. This is where I think you may be able to help me hopefully. Is there some way I can copy this address and send it to a bitcoin cash wallet. After all it is my address, my money. So you know I am incredibly illiterate when it comes to this sort of thing

Comment: Access to the destination via an exchange is not the same as a wallet on your PC or other device. Is the destination wallet on Coinbase? If not, what program/service are you using to service that wallet?

Comment: Im sorry Cleanmarker I am not very good at this, I can see the full transaction on coinbase, as that is what I use to buy bitcoins.

Comment: It was only a small amount of money, but it was to buy something important. Everything I do is through Coinbase, I use the wallets they have for me, I buy the coins and now Bitcoin Cash and send it straight away to an address that is a one off generated address each time.

Comment: No worries James. If it's a Coinbase account that received the BTC in a BCH account then the original statement they made to you stands. Because of security reasons they don't allow programmers access to unencrypted wallet key or recovery codes. This means while they COULD do it in an extreme scenario, they probably have to bug the 1 person they trust to access it (Because they will need at least one person able/trusted to deal with these kinds of things). Unless they can tack on a large fee to warrant all the work the response is simply "it's gone". Wish i could help more. Welcome to BSE.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Cleanmarker.

Comment: I have learned a harsh lesson.

Comment: Fortunately it wasn't loads of money that affects me. I was just getting too blasé and thankfully as I say its minimal cash in the grand scheme of things. Will never make that mistake again. What I just dont get is I had a couple of pounds sterling in my bitcoin cash wallet in coinbase. I don't why it would be there if I have never dealt with bitcoin cash ever, as I would have made this mistake before. That is the really weird thing. Anyways what kind of dogs you got and where are you based. I live in Scotland, I was born in Glasgow and my dog is a mixed from a rottweiler and bull mastiff

Comment: I'm glad you're taking it well. We've all made mistakes. There are some real horror stories on here and the internet in general. People loosing what would be equal to $1.4 million due to a hack for example. (A security mistake, process mistake, address mistake etc). One thing blockchain is not: forgiving. I'm in the north eastern US with 2 white huskies. I just imagined a gigantic rottweiler.